Identifiers with leading underscore defined in a linker script
Per the C standard section 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers

All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.

and

If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.

I understand that the referenced 7.1.4 is for the note 187 stating:

Because external identifiers and some macro names beginning with an underscore are reserved, implementations may provide special semantics for such names. For example, the identifier _BUILTIN_abs could be used to indicate generation of in-line code for the abs function. Thus, the appropriate header could specify
#define abs(x) _BUILTIN_abs(x)

Now, the common pattern (as shown in many reputable online resources, including numerous SO questions/answers) to define linker script symbols with leading underscores such as
  .bss :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _bss_start = .;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _bss_end = .;
  } >RAM

and then refer to these symbols in the C code by declaring like
extern char _bss_start[];
extern char _bss_end[];

or similar. From the cited standard excerpts I gather that these declarations are undefined behavior. Is that correct or I am misreading something? Is there any proper naming convention for linker exported symbols that do not violate the C standard (I understand that we can simply use the proper C naming, but apparently there is some reason people insist on the special naming)?

Using code with undefined behavior does not violate the C standard. It is undefined by the standard, not forbidden by the standard. If your C implementation (including the linker) defines what happens, then it is defined behavior in your C implementation.

The entire concept of a linker script is outside the scope of the C standard, but supposing that you have an implementation that documents the external symbols _bss_start and _bss_end as usable by application code, then using them makes your program have implementation-defined behavior, not undefined behavior.  However any such usage becomes undefined behavior if the application is moved to an implementation that doesn't provide and document those symbols.

@zwol Does it mean that linker script is an acceptable "extension" to the implementation when it comes to the mainstream compilers (as in gcc and friends) ? For instance if I have a static  analyzer complaining about this code, I can rightfully consider it as a false positive?

@EricPostpischil Understood. But does the code above constitute UB as per the standard, or the linker script is considered a part of "implementation" ?

@EugeneSh. Did you write that linker script yourself or was it supplied by the implementation?

@zwol Not shipped with the toolchain, but written in-house, if it is your question.

Yes. So then it's part of the program, and abstractly it ought to be defining symbols in the program's namespace (bss_start and bss_end maybe).  The best way to think about this is that symbols defined by linker scripts are no different than symbols defined by .o files.

@EugeneSh. linker has to be considered as a port of implementation if implementation requires it to generate an executable program.

@zwol: The C standard specifies the interpretation of C source code. It says nothing about linker scripts, regardless of whether they define reserved identifiers in a C name space, define non-reserved identifiers, or both, or neither. Any use of a linker script is simply not defined by the C standard. It does not matter whether somebody considers it part of the implementation or not. It is just undefined by the C standard.

@EricPostpischil The C standard also says nothing about the interpretation of an object file compiled from a Fortran program, but I think you will agree with me that, if you link an object file compiled from Fortran with an object file compiled from C, for the program-as-a-whole to have well-defined behavior per the C standard, the symbols defined by the Fortran object file need to be within C's application namespace. Yes? Well then, it's the exact same thing for symbols defined by a linker script.

@zwol: Re “well-defined behavior per the C standard”: No, the behavior of the program will not be defined by the C standard. The C standard says nothing about linking C programs with FORTRAN programs. For the program to have defined behavior, the definition must come from something beyond the C standard, such as the linker documentation and the platform ABI. There is simply no reason to expect that definition of program behavior always has to come from the C standard.

You're being much more pedantic than I think is appropriate for this conversation.  Do you agree that if the symbols defined by the Fortran object file aren't in the C application namespace then the program-as-a-whole definitely does have undefined behavior per the C standard?  Note that "does have undefined behavior per the C standard" is, in my view, a significantly stronger statement than "the behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard alone".

I'm not sure why you would want to know the start and end of BSS unless this is used by some pre-main startup code, in which case it could be considered part of the implementation for your special platform.

@IanAbbott These linker script symbols are indeed frequently used by the "CRT" start-up code and I don't quite see why the application would use them at all. There is no requirement that the "implementation" has be written in conforming ISO C. Quite often the start-up code is written in assembler even.

@Lundin, @Ian This is just an example. If you don't like bss, think of _some_reserved_section_start for some specific data allocation.

@Lundin Re: "implementation" has be written in conforming ISO C": do you think that it's possible to write an implementation in "conforming ISO C" (i.e. an [entire] implementation is a strictly conforming program)? Does this question need to be asked separately?

@pmor It is definitely possible, as you can write a new C compiler using existing C compiler and it is simply speaking a fancy translator from text to binary. But it is also definitely not required.

@pmor Depends on the target. It's possible to write an entire CRT in pure C for Cortex M microcontrollers for example - in fact I have done so in the past. But that's assuming that the linker (script) takes care of misc stuff for you like memory segment allocation.

The reason why leading undercore is reserved is because it might be used by the "implementation" - that is, the compiler + libraries.
The part of the code using extern char _bss_start[]; etc would be the "CRT" start-up code, which is often considered part of the implementation, particularly if delivered together with the compiler. Then it need not be written in conforming C - in fact it is often written at least partially in assembler.
In order to have a conforming C compiler which can create conforming C programs, then all objects of static storage duration need to be initialized at a point before main() is called (see C17 5.1.2). Which in turn means that there is need for a CRT to do that, particularly on ROM-based computers like microcontrollers. And in order for the CRT to perform static initialization in this case, it needs access to the mentioned symbols. But the CRT might as well be written in assembler and using some manner of "import" command.
Other compilers/linkers which are not of the gcc flavour sometimes solves this by having a name such as bss as some manner of pre-defined symbol which is accessible to the CRT without treating it as a declared variable with a certain linkage.
No matter the compiler, I see no apparent need to name the segment starting with an underscore unless this is intentionally meant to be used by the implementation alone.
